# C11 equivalent of POSIX flockfile()?

Tags: c, thread-safety, posix

Both POSIX and C11 require that streams have an associated lock to prevent data races and interleaving.  POSIX documents `flockfile()` and related functions to allow thread-safe I/O to span multiple calls.  Is there an equivalent C function?  I don't recall one and haven't been able to find one mentioned, which doesn't necessarily mean one doesn't exist.

On a related note, is it safe to assume any implementation claiming POSIX conformance will respect `flockfile()` when using C11 threads.h?  I think most major POSIX-compliant C implementations that support threads.h do so by building on pthreads, which would imply such an assumption is usually safe.  However, multithreading is hard, and it would be helpful to know of exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Both POSIX and C11 require that streams have an associated lock to prevent data races and interleaving.

Yes, but there is no requirement on the particular form of that lock, nor does C have any requirement to make that lock directly accessible to programs, nor any standard mechanism for doing so.

> POSIX documents flockfile() and related functions to allow thread-safe I/O to span multiple calls. Is there an equivalent C function?

No published version of the C language specification documents an analogue of `flockfile()`, `ftrylockfile()`, or `funlockfile()`.  A strictly conforming C11 or C17 program wanting to provide for preventing calls to I/O functions by different threads being interleaved will (because it is strictly conforming) be using the C threads library on an implementation that does not define the macro `__STDC_NO_THREADS__`. Such a program can use that library's mutex implementation for the purpose.  There is no standard way to directly access any locks associated directly with individual `FILE` objects.

> On a related note, is it safe to assume any implementation claiming
> POSIX conformance will respect flockfile() when using C11 threads.h?

To the best of my knowledge, the POSIX C language interfaces are still defined in terms of C99 specifically, so POSIX is blind to C11 threads.  In that sense, no, it is not safe to assume that POSIX provisions about the behavior of threads will apply to C11 threads.

> I
> think most major POSIX-compliant C implementations that support
> threads.h do so by building on pthreads, which would imply such an
> assumption is usually safe. However, multithreading is hard, and it
> would be helpful to know of exceptions.

In practice, it is my expectation that C11 and later implementations on POSIX systems will ensure that C11 threads in fact do have the semantics of POSIX threads, whether by implementing C11 threads on top of POSIX threads or by some other means.  It is reasonable, then, to hope that C11 threads will interoperate as desired with `flockfile()`, but not reasonable to omit unit tests probing that detail specifically.

Note also that in a context such as this, "usually safe" is a tricksome way of saying "unsafe".

Answer (score 0):

Windows implementation in Stockfish:

```
void flockfile(FILE *F)
{
  if ((F >= (&__iob_func()[0])) && (F <= (&__iob_func()[_IOB_ENTRIES-1]))) {
    _lock(_STREAM_LOCKS + (int)(F - (&__iob_func()[0])));
    F->_flag |= _IOLOCKED;
  } else
    EnterCriticalSection(&(((_FILEX *)F)->lock));
}

void funlockfile(FILE *F)
{
  if ((F >= (&__iob_func()[0])) && (F <= (&__iob_func()[_IOB_ENTRIES-1]))) {
    F->_flag &= ~_IOLOCKED;
    _unlock(_STREAM_LOCKS + (int)(F - (&__iob_func()[0])));
  } else
    LeaveCriticalSection(&(((_FILEX *)F)->lock));
}
```

https://github.com/syzygy1/Cfish/blob/5dbf00f9ffae28b0c96a713e897d718204af73e9/src/misc.c#L299

or how Android it does:

```
void
flockfile(FILE * fp)
{
    LockTable*  t = lock_table_lock();
    if (t != NULL) {
        FileLock**  lookup = lock_table_lookup(t, fp);
        FileLock*   lock   = *lookup;
        if (lock == NULL) {
            pthread_mutexattr_t  attr;
            /* create a new node in the hash table */
            lock = malloc(sizeof(*lock));
            if (lock == NULL) {
                lock_table_unlock(t);
                return;
            }
            lock->next        = NULL;
            lock->file        = fp;
            pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
            pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
            pthread_mutex_init( &lock->mutex, &attr );
            *lookup           = lock;
        }
        lock_table_unlock(t);
        /* we assume that another thread didn't destroy 'lock'
        * by calling fclose() on the FILE*. This can happen if
        * the client is *really* buggy, but we don't care about
        * such code here.
        */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock->mutex);
    }
}
```

https://source.codeaurora.org/external/gigabyte/qrd-gb-ssss-7225/plain/android/bionic/libc/stdio/flockfile.c

Comment: The question seems to be asking for a mechanism based (only) on standard C.  That would not be this.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, Microsoft standard ;-)